# Easy way to add a background image to the default android notification layout

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out how to add a background image to the default android notification layout without having to use a custom notification layout. Is this possible or do i really have to re-create the default notification layout?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create custom notification. then also you can go to this link for further information.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html